# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have dynamic views that I add into linear layout after this I get child that I added to linear layout and set tag to them to identify each dynamic layout when clicking on it when I'm clicking on dynamic layout to replace fragment to seeing detail of clicked view I'm getting this error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
```

here is what I'm doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < leafletList.getChildCount(); i++){
        leafletList.getChildAt(i).setTag(i);
    }
```

here is what I'm doing when clicking on dynamic view

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fragment.replaceLeaflet((Integer)view.getTag(), data);
        }
    });
```

where `(Integer)view.getTag()` is null, why is it null? anyway I'm setting the tag to each of them

edited:
this is how I'm adding dynamic views in linear layout defined in xml

```
String[] disease = {"Colds","Cough"};
    for(int i = 0; i < disease.length ; i++){
        DrReportLeafletLayout leaflet = new DrReportLeafletLayout(getActivity(), disease[i], this, disease);
        leafletList.addView(leaflet);
    }
```

crash stack:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.myhealthathand.hah.dev, PID: 25104
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.myhealthathand.hah.customviews.DrReportLeafletLayout$1.onClick(DrReportLeafletLayout.java:55)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: @ArashHatami But why would that avoid the same null pointer exception?

Comment: Can you please add some more code for better visualization...

Comment: what is your view type ? you can define a `TextView` with **Gone** visibility and put/get you tag here @blackHawk

Comment: the dynamic view itself is relative layout

Comment: so you can define a simple `TextView` and set you tag here for each one @blackHawk

Comment: I think the way you are setting tag is wrong. Meaning its not getting set to exact child that's why the child view which will return you tag is giving you null. Can you please add some more code for better visualization...

Comment: @NikhilLotke I suspect this but unable to find out where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to add tag to the view it should be rule that it should be set where the view is created